# Upload a Scorm File to a Course in Moodle with Web service

Tags: web-services, soap-client, moodle, scorm2004, joomdle

I have already created a course to Moodle using joomdle WS "joomdle_create_course" using a Java client through SOAP protocol. After, I have uploaded a SCORM package file with WS "core_files_upload" in my personal area.
Now I want to link this Scorm file with my course through WS !! How can I do?

Do you know what are the parameters of "core_files_upload" (such as filearea, component, itemid, filepath...) I have to use to collocate the file in the exact path of course stored in Moodle?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the API documentation inside your moodle instance

**/moodle/admin/webservice/documentation.php**

The function `core_files_upload` has the following parameters:

```
Array 
(
    [contextid] => int        
    [component] => string        
    [filearea] => string        
    [itemid] => int        
    [filepath] => string        
    [filename] => string        
    [url] => string        
)
```